# Liens vers des sources douteuses du point de vue de la législation

Tags: support

Dans le cadre d'une réponse à une question, est-il autorisé d'insérer un lien vers une ressource que l'on soupçonne fortement de ne pas respecter les copyrights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Légalement, c'est autorisé. Les [conditions d'utilisation du site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) n'en parlent pas. Les modérateurs font respecter les règles de Stack Exchange mais [ne se mêlent pas de questions de droits d'auteur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137846/policy-on-links-either-directly-or-indirectly-to-pirate-content)¹.

En revanche, c'est déconseillé. S'il y a une ressource douteuse qui traite d'un sujet et une autre plus fréquentable et de qualité comparable, merci de préférer la ressource fréquentable. Et si la ressource douteuse n'est pas essentielle à la réponse, il vaut mieux éviter le lien.

¹  <sub>Par contre, le plagiat est [explicitement interdit](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) et les modérateurs font respecter cette interdiction.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Providing links to resources of which you know that they violate copyright is known as [contributory copyright infringement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributory_copyright_infringement) and should be avoided.

See also this [answer to the question "Is it infringement to give a link to a copyrighted file?"](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/4374) on Law Stack Exchange.

I know Stack Exchange isn't Wikipedia, but [Wikipedia prohibits links to materials that violate copyright](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Links_to_other_websites#Restrictions_on_linking).